# C# create outlook message with created PDF file attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I would like to know, how I could attach my created PDF file with Windows Form Data into a new outlook email message. With the following code I create the PDF. I could write it in the same else brackets:

```
else {
CreatePDF();
//This is an example EmailMessage();
}

private void EmailMessage()
    {
        try
        {                
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                this.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
            mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
            mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            throw new Exception("cDocument: Error occurred trying to Create an Outlook Email"
                                + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
        }
    }

public void CreatePdf()
{

    try
    {
        string imageFile = "";
        System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                //pictureBox1.Image();
            }
            //==================add firstname 
            if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Trim() != "")
            { imageFile = "C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd MMMM hh-mm-ss tt") + textBox1.Text; }
            else
            { imageFile = "C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd MMMM hh-mm-ss tt") + "Rectangle"; }


            bitmap.Save(imageFile + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            formToImage(imageFile);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}`
```

Comment: What is the output of `CreatePDF`? is it a file in the file system? or a `byte[]` in memory?

Comment: What is the type of application you are creating? An outlook addin or a stand alone application?

Comment: A stand alone windows C# application developed with visual studio 2015.

Comment: Please check my answer Yacoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an attachment to a `MailItem`, you can use [`Attachments.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx) like this:

```
mailItem.Attachments.Add(filename);
```

where `filename` is the path on the file system of the file that you want to add.

In your case that would be `imageFile + ".bmp"`.

Comment: I'll try this but can you tell me, where I can download the assembly which works with the following namespace?: 
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Comment: If you have outlook installed, you can simply add a reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.0 Object Library via Add Reference -> COM

Comment: But you should already have this since you have code that uses `Outlook.MailItem`

Comment: No I haven't :/ I cant find that assembly where to download it

Comment: Do you have outlook installed? If not, I don't think this is going to work.

Comment: I'm downloading it now...I totally forgot to download the free version...I'll let you know if the code works, after I installed outlook

Comment: It worked to Create the Email message with Content, subject and reciptient :)))